# Que hacen estas funciones?

Tags: python

```
def unionInterseccion():

    a=list(map(int,input("Introduce los numeros de la primera lista (Separados mediante espacios):").split()))
    b=list(map(int,input("Introduce los numeros de la segunda lista (Separados mediante espacios) :").split()))

    A=list(set(a)|set(b))
    B=list(set(a)&set(b))

    print('Union de las listas:',A)
    print('Interseccion de las listas:',B)

unionInterseccion()
```

Resulta que mi profesor me ha enseñado a utilizar funciones de python como set y map, pero me preguntaba como sería este programa más desarrrado. Me refiero a sin utilizar set y map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **map**

El primer caso, `map`, es muy simple. `map` simplemente toma una función (o cualquier callable) como primer argumento y un iterable como segundo. Luego retorna otro iterable resultado de aplicar (mapear) a cada item del iterable original la función.

En tu caso, seria lo mismo que:

```
a = [int(num) for num in input("Introduce los números de la primera lista (Separados mediante espacios):").split()]
```

o sin listas por compresión:

```
nums = input("Introduce los numeros de la primera lista (Separados mediante espacios):")

a = []
for num in nums.split():
    a.append(int(num))
```

Es decir, `map` applica `int()` sobre cada item de la lista salida de `str.split()`, que contendrá cadenas de la forma `["1", "23", "45"]`.

Con `list(map(...))` iteras sobre el iterable y construyes una lista con sus items, que quedaría `[1, 23, 45]`, resultado de `[int("1"), int("23"), int("45")]`

---

### **set**

El caso de `set` es algo más complejo. El builtin `set` permite construir conjuntos, son contenedores que se implementan mediante tablas hash lo que hace que las búsquedas en ellos sean muy eficientes. Son por definición **desordenados** (no mantienen el orden de inserción de los items) y **no permiten items repetidos**.

Cuando haces `set(a)` lo que haces es construir un conjunto a partir de los items de la lista `a` e indirectamente eliminar cualquier duplicado (numero repetido) que exista. El conjunto tendrá por tanto los mismos números que `a`, pero sin un orden preestablecido y sin repeticiones.

- El operador `A | B` lleva a cabo una operación conocida como **unión de conjuntos**. Un elemento está en la unión si, y sólo si, pertenece al conjunto `A` **o**  pertenece al conjunto `B`. Es decir, **si está en alguno de los dos**. Es equivalente a usar el método `set.union`, en tu caso `set(a).union.(set(b))`
- El operador `A & B` lleva a cabo la operación conocida como **intersección de conjuntos**, un elemento está en la intersección si, y solo si, está **presente en ambos conjuntos**. Es equivalente a usar el método `set.intersection`, en tu caso `set(a).intersection.(set(b))`

Sin usar conjuntos, una implementación muy burda e ineficiente, pero que ilustra la idea sería:

```
a = [1, 3, 7, 3, 4]
b = [3, 7, 3, 8, 8]  


intersección = []
for n in a:
    if n in b and n not in intersección:
        intersección.append(n)
for n in b:
    if n in a and n not in intersección:
        intersección.append(n)
print(intersección)


unión = []
for n in a:
    if n not in unión:
        unión.append(n)
for n in b:
    if n not in unión:
        unión.append(n)
print(unión)
```

Obviamente la eficiencia es pésima, a diferencia de la búsqueda en tablas hash, en una lista debemos recorrerla (en el peor de los caso completa) para ver si un item está o no en ella. En este caso iteramos sobre el conjunto de listas (no siempre completamente) 110 veces para la intersección y 60 para la unión si no me fallan las cuentas... Se pueden fusionar los cuatro ciclos en dos y hay algunas forma más eficientes de conseguirlo, pero nada como la potencia que ofrecen los conjuntos. Si queremos mantener el orden en Python >= 3.7 podemos usar diccionarios teniendo solo en cuenta las claves.

Enlaces de interés:

- [`map` (Documentación oficial, en inglés)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [`set` (Documentación oficial, en inglés)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)
- [Operaciones con conjuntos (Wikipedia)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operaciones_con_conjuntos)

Answer (score 5):

Como no hace falta explicarte qué son las funciones `map` y `set`, te cuento rápidamente lo que hacen:

### map

`map` aplica una función a una *secuencia* de elementos, entiendiendo por secuencia *listas, iteradores y generadores*. Aunque se usa mucho en otros lenguajes de tipo funcional, en python casi no lo verás puesto que es más práctico usar las llamadas *"comprensiones de listas"* y *"expresiones generadoras"*.

Así una expresión

```py
res = map(f, lista)
```

es equivalente a

```py
res = []
for x in lista:
    res.append(f(x))
```

Con la salvedad de que `map` devuelve un interador, no una lista. Por eso hace falta convertirlo a lista con el constructor `list`. Esto también quiere decir que la función no se va a evaluar hasta que sea necesario. Por ejemplo:

```py
res = map(lambda x: 1/(x-3), [1,2,3])
x = next(res)  # --> -0.5
y = next(res)  # --> -1.0
```

Si hiciéramos otro `next` nos daría error al evaluar el último elemento de la lista.

Visto lo que hace, veamos la forma equivalenete más común de hacer *maps* en python:

```py
res = (f(x) for x in lista)
```

Esta es una *expresión generadora* que admite muchísimas posibilides y que te aconsejo que domines bien. Y si lo que quieres es obtener una lista, en vez de usar el constructor `list`, es más directo transformarla en una *compresión de listas* de esta forma:

```py
res = [f(x) for x in lista]
```

Tu código ejemplo se transformaría así:

```py
def unionInterseccion():

    a = [int(i) for i in input("Introduce...").split()]
    b = [int(j) for j in input("Introduce...").split()]

...
```

### set

`set` es un *constructor* de conjuntos (*sets*), un grupo de elementos sin repeticiones.

Cuando se hace `list(set(...))` lo que se pretende es crear una lista sin elementos repetidos. Hay que tener en cuenta que, mientras que una lista sus elementos están ordenados, en un conjunto no se garantiza un orden de sus elementos:

```py
>> lista = [1, 2.1, 0.3, 1]                                                                                                  

>> list(set(lista))                                                                                        
[0.3, 1, 2.1]
```

Si lo quieres desarrollado:

```py
res = []
for x in lista:
    if x not in res:
        res.append(x)
```

En las versiones recientes de python se ve poco el uso del constructor `set`. Lo habitual es crear también los conjuntos con generadores. Tu código podría quedar así:

```py
def unionInterseccion():

    a = {int(i) for i in input("Introduce...").split()}
    b = {int(j) for j in input("Introduce...").split()}

...
```

Las operaciones con conjuntos son muy potentes. Ya que hemos visto ejemplos de compresiones de listas, es muy fácil reimplementarlas con ellas:

```py
# A = list(a | b)
A = list(set(list(a)+list(b)))
A = list(a) + [x for x in b if x not in a]

# B = list(a & b)
B = [x for x in a if x in b]
```