# ordenar elementos de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Se que una manera de ordenar las listas es con sort() y sorted() pero en este caso busco ordenar **el contenido de los elementos** así:

```
lista = ['645', '312']
```

resultado esperado:

```
lista = ['123', '456']  #Así
lista = ['456', '123']  #O así, es irrelevante para lo que necesito
```

Lo he intentado especificando el indice, utilizando la función join y split y no lo consigo, siempre me da algún error o un resultado no deseado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente no quieres ordenar la lista, sino ordenar cada uno de sus items, en este caso cadenas. Por lo tanto, debes aplicar el ordenamiento sobre ellos, no sobre la lista.

Las cadenas no tienen ningún método `sort` como las listas, para empezar son inmutables, por lo que para ordenarla tendrás que crear una nueva cadena si o si.

Puedes valerte del builtin `sorted` y `str.join`:

```
lista = ['645', '312']
lista = ["".join(sorted(item)) for item in lista]
```

o si alguien es un enamorado de la programación funcional:

```
 lista = list(map("".join, map(sorted, lista)))
```

> ```
> >>> lista
> ['456', '123']
> ```

Si quieres hacerlo in-place, sin crear una nueva lista, puedes hacer algo como:

```
lista = ['645', '312']

for index, item in enumerate(lista):
    lista[index] = "".join(sorted(item))
```

Comment: Perfecto, aunque no sé para que sirve la función map() pero investigaré a ver que tal.

Comment: Aquí tienes una pregunta que te puede ayudar con lo de map: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/350716/15089. No obstante la lista por compresión creo que es más legible y más eficiente, pero quise dejar la opción de todas formas. Un saludo.